# How to return the number of rows that do not match the join condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables tb_acct and tb_txn

```
tb_acct (acct_num, acct_name)
tb_txn (txn_memo, originator_acct_num, receiver_acct_num)
```

`tb_txn` can be joined with `tb_acct` on either `originator_acct_num` and `receiver_acct_num`

I want to write one query to return number of records in tb_acct whose acct_num does not match with both originator_acct_num and receiver_acct_num, i.e. all those records that cannot be tied back to tb_acct table.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you mean `originator_acct_num` OR `receiver_acct_num`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what you asked:

```
SELECT
  Count(*)
FROM
   tb_acct A
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM
         tb_txn T
      WHERE
         A.acct_num = T.originator_acct_num
         OR A.acct_num = T.receiver_acct_num
   )
;
```

But I wonder if what you meant was:

```
SELECT
   Count(*)
FROM
   tb_txn T
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM
         tb_acct A
      WHERE
         T.originator_acct_num = A.acct_num
         OR T.receiver_acct_num = A.acct_num
   )
;
```

There is some small confusion over whether you want accounts that are not represented in *both* columns (so my queries would need to be modified to split the `OR` to two `EXISTS` clauses) or whether you want accounts that are not represented in *either* column (what I wrote for you).

Comment: You are right, I meant what you wondered. Sorry for posting it incorrectly. Thanks a lot. Will run the query and accept the answer if it works correctly.

Comment: Did you possibly want not the count of transaction rows but the count of unique account numbers in the transactions table that don't match the accounts table?

Comment: I want the count of txn rows that don't match neither the original_acct_num nor the receiver_acct_num on tb_acct table.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear whether you mean that either doesn't tie back or both.  But, the same structure works.  The version where a mismatch on either side causes a failure is:

```
select t.*
from tb_txn t
where not exists (select 1 from tb_acct a where a.acct_num = t.originator_acct_num) or
      not exists (select 1 from tb_acct a where a.acct_num = t.receivor_acct_num);
```

Change the `or` to `and` if both need to fail to match.